# Please help me with my project

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether

I have been given the final year project of fake brand detection using blockchain. I am a complete beginner in anything related to blockchain or ethereum. Can anyone help me any way where to start. I do not have time to learn blockchain from scratch. So please help me how to do this project. I searched for many youtube video and github repository but all in vain. You could help me with steps to create this project or any link which can help me with this project. I looked through various papers as well. But it gives a very basic answer. Please help me